# Canceling request validation using HttpHandler on IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an application that has to deal with getting "special" characters in its URL (like &, +, %, etc). When I'm sending a request to the application using these characters (of course I'm sending them escaped) I'm getting "Bad Request" response code with the message "ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL". Tracing the request shown me that the error was thrown from the "Authentication Module".

I've searched a bit and found that every page has a ValidateRequest and changing its value to false solves the problem. Unfortunately I'm using Httphandler. Does anyone know how to stop the request validation using http handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem (creating an IHttpHandler that needed to receive requests with special characters in the URL).  I had to do two things to fix it:

1. Create the following DWORD registration entry with a value of 1: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\VerificationCompatibility`
2. In the web.config, set the allowDoubleEscaping attribute of the requestFiltering element to true.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got it working by setting validateRequest="false" as well as requestValidationMode="2.0", like below. No registry edits.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  ...
  <pages ... validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wholesale changes at the application or machine level were not acceptable to me. I only had one parameter that a client was sending incorrectly that I needed to scrub.

I found that when a request is made with html or other potentially dangerous items in the query string, you can scrub the string by using the `context.Request.RawUrl` and, once the query string is scrubbed, use `context.RewritePath(scrubbedUrl)`.

1. First thing in the handler, get the `context.Request.RawUrl`
2. Scrub the bad request RawUrl for bad input
3. `context.RewritePath(srubbedUrl)`
4. Profit

It seems like request validation only cares about accessing `context.Request.Params[]`, so if you scrub and rewrite path (to the same path) before the Params collection is accessed, you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me-
Create the following DWORD registration entry with a value of 1: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\VerificationCompatibility`

In the `web.config`, set the `allowDoubleEscaping` attribute of the `requestFiltering` element to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the modules with

```
<httpModules>
  <clear />
</httpModule>
```

to make the request get to your handler. Or maybe you can remove the specific modules that are stopping your request.

This is the list of modules loaded by default in ASP.NET 2.0 from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9b9dh535(VS.80).aspx)

```
<httpModules>
     <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
     <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
     <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" />
     <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
     <add name="PassportAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.PassportAuthenticationModule" />
     <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
     <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
     <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" />
     <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />
     <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that there are some necessary modules that validate the url so I need to find out how to remove the validation and not the modules...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET Framework 4.5, you can use the [`Unvalidated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated) property on `HttpRequest` or `HttpRequestBase` to access form, query string and URL data in a way that will not trigger request validation. If you avoid accessing these values in any other way (including in helper methods or other HTTP modules running in the same request), you will not require anything else to avoid request validation.

Answer (score -1):

You can set validateRequest to false in the pages section of the web.config. Maybe that works for HttpHandlers as well?