# How to change Validate Request to True/False in IIS Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis-7

Can you please help in finding a way to change Validate Request to True/False in IIS using PowerShell for a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the configuration settings of a specific web site or application using the [Set-WebConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807820.aspx) cmdlet.

In your case you'll have to set the value of the `<pages validateRequest="true" />` attribute to `false`:

```
Set-WebConfiguration "//system.web/pages/@validateRequest" IIS:\Sites\MyWebSite -Value $false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Canceling request validation using HttpHandler on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287065/canceling-request-validation-using-httphandler-on-iis-7) and this [Canceling request validation using HttpHandler on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287065/canceling-request-validation-using-httphandler-on-iis-7)

You should just change registry setting, so this code should do the trick for you:

```
Set-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET -name VerificationCompatibility -Value 1
```

Comment: Changing that setting will affect the entire server and not just a specific web site or application.